# How to disable Ctrl+K shortcut for Chrome when trying to indent for Stack Overflow?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts

I really wonder how to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut for Chrome so I can indent my code in Stack Overflow. Or is there any other way to indent code in Stack Overflow? I updated my Chrome to the newest version and also tried extensions but all failed. I tried to ask in Stack Overflow but they let me ask here.

Answer (score 0):

> I really wonder how to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut for Chrome so I can indent my code in Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately, this confuses me. I am assuming that you no longer want `Ctrl + K` to bring up the `Search` functionality in the Chrome address bar? But how does this affect Stack Overflow?

With Chrome 76 and no extensions, Stack Exchange answer boxes seem to override this functionality (i.e. `Ctrl + K` allows you to toggle indents (4 spaces) if you start from the beginning of a line). So you should still be able to indent normally using that shortcut. You may want to clarify exactly what problem(s) you are experiencing.

> Or is there any other way to indent code in Stack Overflow?

If you mean by shortcuts, I am not personally aware of any. But you can simply use 4 (or more) spaces for indenting code if you wish.

Comment: My chrome version is 78.0.3904.87 but it seems chrome's ctrl+k overrides the stack overflow ctrl + k.